# Nested scaffold generator for Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, nested, generator, scaffolding

Is there a scaffold generator for Rails 3 that accommodates nested resources?

Rails 2.3 had

https://github.com/jeremyf/rspec_on_rails_nested_scaffold

https://github.com/mahkhaled/NestedRestfulScaffold

https://github.com/nilesh/nested-scaffold

but I don't find anything similar for Rails 3.

For quick prototypes, it'd be convenient not to have to tweak views after running a scaffold generator for nested resources.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I just created one. 
https://github.com/amatsuda/nested_scaffold

Hope this helps!

Comment: unfortunately just 3 level nesting :(

Comment: Any difference for rails 4?