# Scaffolding with deep-nested routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, scaffolding

So I have a project that has routes as such:

**routes.rb**

```
resources :projects do
  resources :messages

  resources :lists do
    resources :tasks
  end
end
```

However, I want to add in time tracking for each task that I create, turning my routing into:

**routes.rb**

```
resources :projects do
  resources :messages

  resources :lists do
    resources :tasks do
      resources :timetracks
    end
  end
end
```

I want to scaffold the basics of my MVC and then go in and make necessary changes or edits, but how do I scaffold so that my controllers and views conform with my routing? Or is that even possible?

---

**To elaborate further**, when I typed this into the console:

`rails generate scaffold timetrack hours:float date:datetime description:string task:references`

I get the normal scaffolding files, but all of the routes are formatted as such:

`http://localhost:3000/timetracks/`

When really, I would like them to be:

`http://localhost:3000/projects/1/lists/1/tasks/1/timetracks/`

I know you can do this manually in the controllers and views, but is there any way I can have this generate while performing my scaffolding?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no way to create nested routes via the standard rails3 scaffolding, however, I did a quick search and came up with this gem: https://github.com/amatsuda/nested_scaffold

For reference, I found it via this similar question: [Nested scaffold generator for Rails 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4174544/nested-scaffold-generator-for-rails-3)

Hope that helps.